# Match 2 strings then print both matches

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, match

I have 2 lists that i want to match and then print the matched values from both list A and list B

```
 import re

A="""
ABB1265 DUE blah blah 
ADD809 DUE blah blah 
blah ADD blah 
TIME 20:33 ADD223 blah blah. 
"""

B = """
GFA
ADD
ABB
TI
"""



pattern = re.compile("(" + "|".join(i.strip() for i in B.strip().splitlines()) + ")")
for line in A.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    m = pattern.match(line)      #Using re.match
    if m:
        print(line,end=",")
        print(m.group(1))
```

This code is matching only words at the start of the line and it also taking strings inside strings

the output currently is this:

```
ABB1265 DUE blah blah,ABB
ADD809 DUE blah blah,ADD
TIME 20:33 ADD223 blah blah.,TI
```

My ideal output is this:

```
    ABB1265 DUE blah blah,ABB 
    ADD809 DUE blah blah,ADD
    blah ADD blah,ADD
    TIME 20:33 ADD223 blah blah.,ADD
```

Comment: you meant 2 strings, not lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 approaches:

```
import re

a = """
ABB1265 DUE blah blah 
ADD809 DUE blah blah 
blah ADD blah 
TIME 20:33 ADD223 blah blah.  
"""

b = """
GFA
ADD
ABB
TI
"""

pat = re.compile(r'({})\d*\b'.format('|'.join(b.split())))

for row in a.splitlines():
    m = pat.search(row)
    if m:
        print(row.strip(), m.group(1), sep=',')
```

The output:

```
ABB1265 DUE blah blah,ABB
ADD809 DUE blah blah,ADD
blah ADD blah,ADD
TIME 20:33 ADD223 blah blah.,ADD
```

---

Or without any regexps (for initial target string):

```
a = """
ABB1265 DUE blah blah 
ADD809 DUE blah blah 
blah ADD blah 
TIME 20:33 ADD223 blah blah.  
"""

b = """
GFA
ADD
ABB
TI
"""

b_keys = b.split()

for row in a.splitlines():
    for k in b_keys:
        if row.startswith(k):
            print(row.strip(), k, sep=',')
            break
```

The output:

```
ABB1265 DUE blah blah,ABB
ADD809 DUE blah blah,ADD
TIME 20:33 ADD223 blah blah.,TI
```

Comment: Thanks guys, the code works though im having an issue with this sample, i have the code TI, and i have a String "time blah ABB blah ", and its taking the word "time" as a match which is wrong it should take ABB

Comment: @Mohannad, so don't write that in comments - change and correct your question with new samples and new result

Comment: @Mohannad, that's what my 2nd approach does, I doubt that you tested it

Comment: I tested it, and my issue is that its printing "TI" and leaving "ADD"

Comment: Thanks, Roman, Work great, though one thing, whats the best approach to convert the print statement to an output.write

Comment: @Mohannad, with this `sys.stdout.write(row.strip() + ',' + m.group(1) + '\n')`

Answer (score 1):

`re` is overkill here, simple `str.strip()` and `str.splitlines()` is enough:

```
A="""
ABB1265 DUE blah blah
ADD809 DUE blah blah
"""

B="""
ABB
ADD
ARR
AWW
"""

print('\n'.join( ','.join(value) for value in zip(A.strip().splitlines(), B.strip().splitlines()) ))
```

Prints:

```
ABB1265 DUE blah blah,ABB
ADD809 DUE blah blah,ADD
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need.

```
import re

A="""
ABB1265 DUE blah blah 
ADD809 DUE blah blah 
"""

B="""
ABB
ADD
ARR
AWW
"""
pattern = re.compile("(" + "|".join(i.strip() for i in B.strip().splitlines()) + ")")
for line in A.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    m = pattern.match(line)      #Using re.match
    if m:
        print(line, m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
'ABB1265 DUE blah blah', 'ABB'
'ADD809 DUE blah blah', 'ADD'
```

Comment: It doesn't print the comma between the 2 values

Comment: `print(", ".join([line, m.group(1)]))` ?

Comment: Thanks, i did 2 separate print lines, though i'm facing another issue now, check the topic again please.